# Defining a "pseudo" column which is a substring() of a char column for selects

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Using Postgres and/or Mysql (latest), I have a column in a table that is a unique-key being a char column and comprises eg. date(8), branch(6), cashier(6), operator(6), sequence(6), reversal(1). These are all numeric values. I am doing this because I think it will be more efficient for Inserts than to create a composite unique key using separate columns for those fields.
 My main question is whether it is possible to define a type of pseudo column being a substring() to allow selects using just a column name to define eg. "operator"? 
An alternative is to use substring() in the select statement which for ad-hoc queries is a little cumbersome.
 Another alternative if a composite unique key is just as efficient (for Inserts), I could use that.
 The table will be very high volume, but only for Inserts and Selects. The Selects will mainly be on the Primary Key which will consist of Account Number (int) and Transaction Number (int).

Comment: What seems efficient today may become a problem tomorrow when you suddenly find that you need to update "operator" when "date" between a last week and a week before. have you actually run some tests to check the performance? Are you sure you will gain more performance by using this approach?

Comment: Never ever combine different pieces of information into a single column. And never ever store dates or number as character values. Using substring for queries will be quite costly in MySQL as it does not allow for function based indexes (nor virtual columns). In Postgres you *could* index the substring expression - but I would still consider that a hack rather than a solid design.

Comment: I agree it's not pretty, and it's not cast in concrete yet. However, if it is a lot faster, the end may justify the means. I am aware however that solutions should be elegant, so I'll try and find an alternative. The aim is to ensure that an external key (as shown) is not duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

The {branch, cashier, operator} triplet looks suspicious, could violate BCNF.I think you should first noramlise your datamodel before denormalising it *for performance reasons*.

{date, branch, sequence} looks like a natural PK to me (two out of three are reserved words, though)

Posted as an answer (Sorry, I cannot comment yet)